# Taut string algorithm and TV-minimization equivalence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given real numbers $y_i's$, consider the following convex optimization problem:
$$
\min_{x_i's} \sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-x_i)^2 + \lambda\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}|x_{i+1}-x_{i}|.
$$
The paper [A Direct Algorithm for 1D Total Variation Denoising](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00675043v2/document) by Laurent Condat claims that this is equivalent to:
$$
\min_{s_i's} \sum_{i=1}^N \sqrt{(1 + (s_i-s_{i-1})^2)} \\
\mbox{subject to}~~ s_0=0, s_N=\sum_{i=1}^Ny_i \\~\mbox{and}~ \left|s_k-\sum_{i=1}^ky_i\right|\leq \lambda, \forall k.
$$
I did see the references therein, especially [Mammen, E; van de Geer, S.:
*Locally adaptive regression splines*. Ann. Statist. 25 (1997), no. 1, 387–413], but following the proof was a bit hard. Would appreciate help in this regard.